# How to make Flask app up and running after server restart?

Tags: python, linux, flask, redhat

What is the recommended way to run Flask app (e.g. via Gunicorn?) and how to make it up and running automatically after linux server (redhat) restart?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at `supervisord`?  it works reasonably well and handles restarting processes automatically if they fail as well as looking after error logs nicely

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about RedHat, but it [looks like](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/migration_planning_guide/sect-networking-upstart) RedHat can use [upstart](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-upstart-event-system-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it) for managing services.

So one way to accomplish this is: Configure an upstart job to start the gunicorn process on boot.

An upstart job file (saved in `/etc/init/mysuperwebapp.conf`) would look like:

```
description "My flask app served by gunicorn"                                                                                                                                 
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
chdir /p/ath/to/directory
exec /path/to/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn ...
```

To manually start the job:

```
$ sudo service mysuperwebapp start
```

Upstart documentation: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/